# I am allocating a case number to the user and I want to print the case number that I have allocated

Tags: python, variables, random, numbers

The problem is that I have allocated a case number to the user and I want it to print the number given to the user,however it displays 'None'.

```
Welcome
Your case number is:
8239
Sending data: None
```

This is the code:

```
while True:
    print('Welcome')
    print('Your case number is:')
    import random
    variable1 = lambda: random.randint(1, 10000)
    print(variable1())
    state=random.getstate()
    print('Sending data:',(random.setstate(state)))
    break
```

Comment: Do not import `random` in the loop, even though it runs just once.

Comment: I'm confused now about what this program does.  Why do you have a **while** loop that executes only once and then breaks?  Why are you importing random and defining a lambda function on each iteration?  What are you doing with the process state?

Comment: It was just a small part of a larger program sorry I forgot to mention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure `random.setstate` returns None. That's why None is being printed.

I don't think you need to muck around with states at all here. Just store the result of `variable1()` and print that.

```
while True:
    print('Welcome')
    print('Your case number is:')
    import random
    variable1 = lambda: random.randint(1, 10000)
    x = variable1()
    print(x)
    print('Sending data:',x)
    break
```

---

Incidentally, there's not much point in having a while loop if you break out of it unconditionally. And there's not much point in creating a function object with `lambda` if you're only going to call it one time. So you can reduce your code to:

```
import random

case_number = random.randint(1, 10000)

print('Welcome')
print('Your case number is:')
print(case_number)
print('Sending data:',case_number)
```

Answer (score 0):

[setstate](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/random.html#random.setstate) has no return value; it simply does its job.  *state* is the value you're setting; perhaps you want to print that, instead?

If you just want to grab and print a random number in that range, the code is much simpler.  For instance, if you just need to generate 5 numbers:

```
import random

for _ in range(5):
    case_id = random.randint(1, 10000)
    print("Case #", case_id)
```

Output:

```
Case # 4842
Case # 5146
Case # 6898
Case # 8274
Case # 658
```

If you need unique numbers, then you'll have to maintain a list of used or unused numbers, checking against that each time.